# NextJS app router - where to put overall state?

Tags: next.js, darkmode, app-router

I am quite new to NextJS development especially with the App router and am a bit confused.

I am building a fairly simple app with a home page and a contact page.

I have a Nav component for my 'navigation' which consists mainly of a toggle to go from darkmode to lightmode.

My layout.js is almost unchanged

```
export const metadata = {
  title: "Test",
  description: "My Next Test",
}

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className="flex flex-col min-h-screen py-3 pl-24 pr-10 bg-black">
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

My page.js in the app folder looks like this

```
import React from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import { clsx } from "clsx"

import Nav from "../components/Nav"
import Footer from "../components/Footer"
import Search from "@/components/Search"

const Home = () => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkmode] = useState(true)
  const [english, setEnglish] = useState(true)

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkmode(!darkMode)
  }

  const toggleEnglish = () => {
    console.log("toggle english,", english)
    setEnglish(!english)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Nav
        english={english}
        toggleEnglish={toggleEnglish}
        darkMode={darkMode}
        toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
      />

      <main
        className={clsx(
          "flex flex-1 flex-col items-start justify-start w-1/2 bg-white dark:bg-black pt-20",
          { dark: darkMode }
        )}
      >
        <h1 className="mb-12 text-3xl text-black dark:text-white">
          Santi van den Toorn
        </h1>
        <p className="mb-8 text-black dark:text-white">
          {english ? (
            <span>
              text
            </span>
          ) : (
            <span>
           text
            </span>
          )}
        </p>
        <Search english={english} />
      </main>

      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

In my contact folder I have a page.js

```
import React from "react"

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>contact</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

My nav component

```
const Nav = ({ darkMode, english, toggleDarkMode, toggleEnglish }) => {
  return (
    <nav className="flex justify-end w-full h-12 bg-black ">
      {english ? (
        <span
          onClick={toggleEnglish}
          className="mr-2 text-white hover:cursor-pointer"
        >
          NL
        </span>
      ) : (
        <span
          onClick={toggleEnglish}
          className="mr-2 text-white hover:cursor-pointer"
        >
          EN
        </span>
      )}
      {darkMode ? (
        <Sun
          color="white"
          size={24}
          onClick={toggleDarkMode}
          className="hover:cursor-pointer"
        />
      ) : (
        <Moon
          color="white"
          size={24}
          onClick={toggleDarkMode}
          className="hover:cursor-pointer"
        />
      )}
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

I dont get how I can also apply the Nav and footer to the contact page
And I need to have the darkmode state in the layout.js to add the 'dark' class to the html element. (I use Tailwind to manage darkmode by selector).

In the past I used to add those stuff to the _app.js file but now I dont get how to elevate the state above the page.js ? I 'ts possibly a stupid question but hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inside you `RootLayout.js` file, you need to add you `Nav` bar and `Footer`. Because it is file which makes the common design layout. Then you have to pass the `children` props.

Then set the `useState` for dark mode and english. Add the 'use client' declarative on the top of the RootLayout so that it can use the `useState` hook.

RootLayout.js

```js
'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './globals.css'; // Your global styles
import Nav from '@/components/Nav';
import Footer from '@/components/Footer';

export const metadata = {
  title: "Test",
  description: "My Next Test",
}

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {

  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(true); 
  const [english, setEnglish] = useState(true); 
  
  const toggleDarkMode = () => setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  const toggleEnglish = () => setEnglish(!english);


  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Nav
        darkMode={darkMode}
        english={english}
        toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
        toggleEnglish={toggleEnglish}
      />
      <body className="flex flex-col min-h-screen py-3 pl-24 pr-10 bg-black">
        {children}
      </body>
      <Footer />
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

Now your `contact` page.js will have the Navbar and Footer.